# Doctrine 2: limit by array of entities or bind an array

Tags: doctrine-orm

I know there is the `CollectionMemberExpression` and of course `IN`.  What I need to do is find a number of users who are members of *x* teams.

```
SELECT u from NAMESPACE\User u LEFT JOIN u.teams t WHERE t.team_id IN(?1)
```

or

```
SELECT u from NAMESPACE\User u LEFT JOIN u.teams t WHERE ?1 MEMBER OF t.teams
```

I can use a simple `IN()`, and while I won't ever get any dirty items, I still like to bind whenever possible.  At the DBAL level you can attach an array of strings/int, saving one from the hideous `implode(',', $ids)`.  Can this be done at the ORM level, `setParameter(1, array);`

So far it looks as though the `implode` will be the way but would really like a better approach.

Thanks in advance.